# Remove only first occurrence of a pandas cell that matches strings in a list

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text

This was originally marked a duplicate by someone but this is in relation to pandas, so different than what it was marked as a duplicate for. 
I am trying to use re.sub to remove the first occurrence per pandas cell of a string that matches my list.
I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "name": [
            "hello kitty hello",
            "hello puppy",
            "it is an helloexample",
            "for stackoverflow",
            "hello world",
        ],
    }
)

strings_to_remove = ["hello", "for", "an"]
```

I want an output like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
      'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
      'name': {0: ' kty hello',
       1: ' puppy',
       2: ' is  example',
       3: ' stackoverflow',
       4: ' world'}}
)
```

Notice how only the first occurrence of hello is removed from df2 under the 'name' column for each cell.
Looking to use something like re.sub but not sure how to get the code to only remove the first occurrence of 'hello' within each cell.  Any ideas?

Comment: why `for` is not removed?

Comment: thanks for pointing this out.  Just remove it.  It should be removed too.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You said each occurrence of `'hello'` only should be removed. Can you please clarify what will happen in this case? `'it an for hello'`. What will be output for this?

Comment: I said the first occurrence.

Comment: @acodejdatam __"but not sure how to get the code to only remove the first occurrence of 'hello' within each cell."__

Comment: You need to review your sample/output. Why `hello` in `ID 3` is removed but `it` in `kitty` of `ID 1` is not.

Comment: @Quang Hoang thank you just updated.

Comment: "You said each occurrence of" - is what you said @Poojan.  I said 'first occurrence'.

Comment: Will `kitty` become `kty`? after removing `it`? Your output is full of missmatch of what you are stating. Please clarify your output better. I dont understand how the fk this question  is closed.

Comment: @Poojan, yes it will.

Comment: Then why `hello kitty hello` output is `kitty hello` and not `kty hello`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can pass how many times you want to substitute value in `re.sub` function

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "name": [
            "hello kitty hello",
            "hello puppy",
            "it is an helloexample",
            "for stackoverflow",
            "hello world",
        ],
    }
)

strings_to_remove = ["hello", "for", "an", "it"]


for word in strings_to_remove:
    df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(word,'',x,1))

df
```

output:

```
    ID  name
0   1   kty hello
1   2   puppy
2   3   is example
3   4   stackoverflow
4   5   world
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I was looking for.  I updated the question as well.

Comment: copy past above code and run. Its working as expected for me.